# Conditional Time Period for Totals

Tags: sql-server, date

I feel like I'm making this harder than it should be. I'm trying to display a sum for month C but this sum must include totals for months A, B & C. Then I need to do the same thing for Month D which includes totals for months B, C & D. Once I have this figured out I need to break it down by individual accounts but that part shouldn't be too difficult.

I have a date table to call on but it doesn't have month start or end dates which seems to be causing my difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to the above issue is to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) in the join statement identifying the date range accepted for the time period.

```
Select *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B CASE WHEN a.DateID >= b.PeriodStart AND a.DateID <= b.PeriodEnd THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
```